# PowerShell Profile is insecure?

Tags: powershell, profile

We recently had a change in our setup so that my doucuments directory is now based on our network rather than locally.

The problem is that every time I open powershell it now complains that my profile is insecure. I don't really want to go down the route of setting the execution policy to `Bypass` just so I can load my profile.

Is there something I can set in the file itself so that PowerShell knows it hasn't been downloaded off the internet. Or can I change where my profile is stored?

I currently have PowerShell 2 installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have three options:

- Sign the file (and set your execution policy to `RemoteSigned` or higher).
- Add the file location to the Intranet zone (see [here](http://setspn.blogspot.ch/2011/05/running-powershell-scripts-from-unc.html) or [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/10/29/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-a-shared-directory/)).
- Set the execution policy to `Unrestricted` or `Bypass`.

Comment: OK cheers, I followed the instructions to sign the file, which was actually a lot less painless than I anticipated. Now I can use `RemoteSigned` again.